# Reload ListView animation on cursor change

Tags: java, android, listview, animation, cursor

I have a ListView with an animation. The animation plays well when the ListView is first loaded. I want the animation to replay when I change the cursor.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@drawable/gradienthorizontal"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_cascade"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector" >
</ListView>
```

I change the cursor here:

```
private void majCurseurListe(long id, boolean choixvente) {
    Cursor curseurPtVente = null;

    if (choixvente) {
        curseurPtVente = mDbHelper
                .listePtsVentes(DBhelper.TYPE_PTVENTE, id);
    } else {
        curseurPtVente = mDbHelper.listePtsVentes(DBhelper.TYPE_PTSERVICE,
                id);
    }

    // Android s'occupe du cycle de vie du curseur
    startManagingCursor(curseurPtVente);
    ((CursorAdapter) getListAdapter()).changeCursor(curseurPtVente);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just invoke

```
listView.startLayoutAnimation();
```